# Changing an argument's value on NSString's initWithFormat:arguments: method

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I'm having a hard time figuring out the following:

I have an initializer method that creates an unused formatted NSString with some NSString arguments that **aren't initialized** like this:

`NSString *initialString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", arg1, arg2];`

Later in my program, I initialize those arguments with some values but when I print out to `NSLog` my `initialString` the arguments remain `null`.
If I check my arguments they're initialized and provide the correct values I gave them.

`initialString` is a strong referenced property of an object while the arguments are `static NSStrings`.

So the conclusion:

1. I want to initialize an NSString with a certain format and certain uninitialized arguments (hard coded) at the beginning of my program.
2. Later on, at runtime, I want to use my initial string and have it read the values from the now initialized arguments.

How could I achieve that? Using pass-by-reference or KVO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not *certain* I understand you, but in order to re-initialize `initialString` with the updated values you will need to call `stringWithFormat:` again with the new values.  This is because `stringWithFormat:` will take whatever value `arg1` and `arg2` are at the time it is called and changes to those values will not affect the formatted string.

It's probably best to put that functionality into a private method that updates the instance variable (I assume it is) whenever `arg1` or `arg2` are changed:

```
- (void)formatInitialStringWithArg1:(id)arg1 andArg2:(id)arg2
{
    self.initialString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", arg1, arg2];
}
```